# Need to verify Real Analysis Proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I wish to verify a proof; solutions to this exercise are not available.

**Lemma**: If  $S \subset \mathbb{Z}$ is bounded from above, it has a maximum element.

**Proof**: If $S$ is bounded from above, it has a supremum, say $b$. Suppose $b \notin S$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we can find some $\epsilon>0$ such that there is no integer $k$ satisfying $b-\epsilon<k<b$. Hence if every $n\in S$ satisfies $n<b$, every $n \in S$ also satisfies $n<b-\epsilon$.

This contradicts $b$ being a supremum. Thus the supremum of $S$ must be an element of $S$, namely its maximum.

**Theorem**: If $x$ is an arbitrary real number, there is exactly one integer $n$ satisfying $n≤x<n+1$.

**Proof**: Let $P = \{k \in \mathbb{Z} | k≤x\}$. This is bounded from above, say by $x$. Hence it has a maximal element $n$.  Moreover, $n+1>x$ for otherwise $n+1 \in P$ which would contradict $n$ being the maximum. The uniqueness of $n$ can be observed by noting that every integer $m$ can be expressed as $m=n+c$ for integer $c$ and also that $n+c≤x<n+c+1$ is untrue for $c≠0$

Comment: You should include in the Lemma an assumption that $S$ is nonempty.

Comment: In the lemma the fact that $Z$ is not dense in $R$ does not imply that $(b-\epsilon,b)\cap Z= \phi.$ Instead ,$(b-\epsilon,b)\cap Z=\phi $ for $b\not \in R$ and for some $\epsilon>0$ follows from the fact that $Z$ is closed in $R$.

Comment: One other minor quibble about wording: when in the lemma you have "say $b$", this is alright because you are introducing a new symbol, "$b$" and this is its definition. But in the proof of the theorem where you have "say by $x$", the "say by" makes no sense as the symbol $x$ is already defined. You should just say "This is bounded above by $x$". Since this is obviously true, that is all that is needed..

Comment: I would say that since $b$ is the supremum of $S$ but $b \not \in S$, there is some $k \in S$ with $b-1<k<b$. Again, since $b$ is the supremum of $S$, there is some $l \in S$ with $k < l < b$. This implies that $0<l-k<1$, which is absurd because $l-k$ is an integer. The way you've written the uniqueness part of the proof of the theorem isn't terribly clear. An alternative would be to prove that $n \leq x < n+1$ implies $n = \max P$.